# Multiple Selectable Images Within a Figure

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to make a figure environment that can select between multiple images. I am not trying to do multiple subfigures but rather a single figure environment that can cycle through multiple images like a slideshow. At this point I don't have any particular format in mind. I am just looking to see if Latex has the ability to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For images with subsequent names there are some easy solutions like `\multiinclude` from beamer or `\animategraphics`